# safari driver facing issues in parallel execution

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

I am running my test cases in safari browser using selenium web driver.

I am using 2.48 for safari and 2.48.2 for selenium web driver in java.

I am facing some issue with safari browser. like below:

```
1. In single run, safari browser communicate with my webserver quickly but if i choose parallel run, safari driver communication becomes very slow.

2.As it takes more time to communicate in parallel execution, elements  remain unclickable and it can not find elements and test cases failed.

3.In parallel execution, its closed suddenly showing an error message.
 "org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45339 ms"
```

Is these known issues in safari driver or how can i get relieved from these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The Safari driver does not support executing multiple simultaneous instances of Safari on the same machine. Parallel execution can only be done using multiple machines, though virtual machines are an acceptable solution.

Comment: is there a best way to use safari driver in selenium or any desired capabilities or any other thing?

Comment: I have also one more question to you, in safari driver, when execution(not parallel) running, after some time, safari driver stops communicating with web server, that means its stuck in loading the page and if i manually refresh the page, safari driver starts again.How i can solve this or is there any best matching in safari driver and selenium webdriver to solve this issue?


Thanks sir in advance.